# Changing a setting in the wp-admin/customize.php reverts CSS styles to parent theme

Tags: customization, wp-admin, child-theme

I have a child theme built ontop of the Cherry Framework theme.

Whenever an admin user goes to wp-admin/customize.php and changes the slider, the CSS gets completely destroyed and needs to be backed up.

Has anyone had any experience with the Cherry framework and why it could be causing this?

**What would I need to add (or remove) to the functions.php to completely disable the customize page to prevent the end user from accidentally causing this problem in the future if they poke around?**

edit:

http://www.blogcontentprovider.com/blog/blog-design/cherry-framework-wordpress-worth-effort/08/09/2013/chrismcelroy

Seems like a common issue with the Cherry framework, anyone seen any solutions?

Can this really be off-topic for the WordPress site? It's about WordPress theming. It's directly related to WordPress development, and not general PHP development.

Comment: yes, I had the (small) experience and it can be summarized as "w(hy)tf people use it?", which to be fair is what I think of all other frameworks in the wordpress world. Unfortunately since your problem is mostly with a 3rd party code and even then it might be some local interaction/bug it is probably going to be off-topic here for one of those reason.

Comment: to make it on-topic, focus on what you want to do, (disable customizer) and leave the reason as a background info.

Comment: Sure, changed the phrasing of the question and bolded the bit about disabling the customizer.

There is plugins that can accomplish it, but I don't want a user 2-3 years down the track disabling something and then nuking the site, so I think I need to do it in the functions.php and comment the reasoning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes were being made in a stylesheet that is auto-generated by the parent theme. In the specific case of the Cherry parent theme (which is widely used in templates sold on themeforest, templatemonster etc), you cannot make stylesheet changes in reserved files such as main-styles.css (Despite them existing in a child theme).

The solution is to either make style changes in the style.css, or to make a stylesheet with a dependancy on main-styles.css, in order to override any auto-generated styles.

I.e.

```
 <?php wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, 'main-styles', $ver, $media ); ?>
```

Can read more about the solution here:

http://www.templatemonster.com/help/wordpress-cherry-framework-keeps-reverting-my-css-changes.html

Comment: In other words: The "Cherry Parent Theme" is broken.